# Flutter Option to mimic cmd+k event in IOS to open/hide virtual keyboard

Tags: ios, dart, flutter

I have a physical keyboard attached to my IOS device, by default the virtual keyboard is hidden. This can be brought back by pressing cmd+k keys on the physical keyboard. Is there a way to programmatically trigger this key event so that we can bring the virtual keyboard by pressing a RaisedButton widget?

thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you can do this by just tapping the little down-arrow button that appears in the lower right corner when the virtual keyboard is hidden.

Comment: @drewster That works for IPad devices, I am looking for the similar option in IPhones .